# My footer DIV will not sit at the bottom of my page

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a footer div that is just a solid colour that I would like to sit at the bottom outside of my container DIV which is called 'mainhome'. I would like it to stretch the entire site. It just keeps sitting on top of my banner - I'm getting lost in the code now so maybe i have just missed something small?

Thank you in advance

MY HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<div class="mainhome">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:23px"><h2>home</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:20px"><h2>about</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:30px"><h2>portfolio</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:27px"><h2>contact</h2></div>
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/es-logo.png" width="170" height="170" /></div> 
      <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:17px"><h2>print</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:25px"><h2>digital</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:38px"><h2>illustration</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:20px"><h2>brand</h2></div>
  </div>
        <div class="mainimage">
        <div id="slider_container">
  <div id="slides">
                <img src="images/slider/emmasteed.png" alt="Emma Steed Graphic Art and Web Design" />
                <img src="images/slider/graphicdesign-desk.png" alt="Emma Steed Graphic Art and Web Design" />
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="bluebar"></div>
        <div class="largemenubutton" style="margin-right:36px"><img src="images/portfolio.png" /></div>
        <div class="largemenubutton" style="margin-right:36px"><img src="images/getintouch.png" /></div>
        <div class="largemenubutton"><img src="images/aboutme.png" /></div>
        </div></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

MY CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.mainhome {
    width: 855px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.header {
    height: 236px;
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    clear:left;
}

.mainimage {
    width: 855px;
    height: 423px;
    background-color:#0C9;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    float:left;
    z-index:-1;
}

#slider_container {
        width:855px;
        height:423px;
        overflow:hidden;
}

.bluebar {
    width: 855px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color:#334d5c;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}

.menubutton-leftside {
    width:60px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:95px;
}

.menubutton-rightside {
    width:60px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:95px;
    text-align:right;
}

h2 {
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#666;
    display:inline;
}

.logo {
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}

.largemenubutton {
    width:261px;
    height:259px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.footer {
    width:100%;
    height: 61px;
    background-color:#334d5c;
    clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like .nameimage needs to be absolutely positioned, but it depends on what you want it to do. Rough example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oAbJy.

Comment: I have this absalutely positioned as i have it just underlapping with the header as this has a drop shadow (http://www.emmasteed.co.uk/Site.jpg) was it removing the absalute that made the footer sit?

Comment: Yes, removing the absolute puts `.mainimage` back in the document flow so the footer stays below it. To get the overlap back, try a negative margin on `.mainimage`, for example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DjuCE.

Keep in mind this just puts the footer below `.mainimage`. If the height of the content in `.mainimage` or `#slider_container` changes dynamically, the footer will move up or down to stay below it. My favorite site for understanding different approaches to this sort of thing is http://learnlayout.com.

Answer (score 0):

likely the easiest thing to do, if you ALWAYS want that to be at the very bottom is just give it a fixed position. Add the following to your CSS for the footer. (you may also have to set height and width on the body to 100%)

```
position: Absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: Thanks - after reading this I did think 'yes of course!' however in Dreamweaver it still sits on top of my 'mainimage' and in the browser it now sits across the images along the bottom and not at the very bottom.

I now have my footer as:
.footer {
 height: 61px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#334d5c;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
}

HTML:
        <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: After trying this - it is not ideally what I want as if the screen size is smaller I can see why this is now sitting above my other images I just want this to sit at the very bottom of my page and not always visible if that makes sense.

Comment: Hi there, one last thing, make 100% sure that you have a 100% height and 100% width set in the css for both your html and your body, otherwise the body or html page won't actually stretch to the end of the page.